# problems with nivo slider light and menu dropdown

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

Hi I have a problem with the nivo slider light in wordpress
and menu dropdown

When I try to down to the other "section" the menu dissapear

This is a problem with z-index or something??
Very thanks

The link is the above

http://www.pymedia.cl/st/

Comment: In which browsers/versions does the problem happen? Could you show a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: all browsers, the problem happen   when i move the cursor to the menu "acerca de" > Quienes somos

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is related to CSS of the `<span>` tags inside the `<a>` tags of your menu's `<li>`. Could you try just removing those spans temporarily or the CSS applied to them?